# I'm using PDFMake on Linux, and it is not displaying the accents, even with the characters on Linux configured as pt_br.UTF-8, not working

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

I'm using RedHat Linux, and i am using the Portuguese language. I'm using PDFMake on Linux, and it is not displaying the accents, even with the characters on Linux configured as "pt_br.UTF-8", not working. On Windows, the same PDF generation script is working normally, but on Linux it is not working, as it is not displaying the accents.

Please, could someone help me see if I'm missing any settings in pdfmake?

Here is the header of my code:

```
let docDefinition = {
                            pageOrientation: 'portrait', 
                            pageSize: 'A4',
                            pageMargins: [20, 20, 20, 35],
                            header: function(page, pages) { 
                                return {
                                    columns: [
                                        {
                                            text: 'Página: ' + page.toString() + ' de ' + pages.toString(),
                                            encoding: 'utf-8',
                                            width: '*',
                                            style: {
                                                fontSize: 8,
                                                alignment: 'right'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    margin: [25, 10]
                                }
                            },
                            styles: {
                                tableExample: {
                                    fontSize: 6,
                                    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                    border: 0
                                },
                                tableHeader: {
                                    bold: true,
                                    fontSize: 6,
                                    color: 'black'
                                }
                            },                                  
                            content: [
                                {
                                    style: 'tableReport',
                                    table: {   
                                        //        1  1b   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
                                        widths: [50, 33, 19, 55, 39, 35, 35, 35, 35, 20, 30, 20, 30], // TOTAL: 414
                                        headerRows: 2,
                                        body: []
                                    },
                                    style: {
                                        fontSize: 8
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            styles: {
                                tableReport: {
                                    margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        
                   rows.push(
                            [
                                {
                                    image: pathLogo,
                                    colSpan: 5,
                                    width: 85,
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    border: [true, true, false, false]
                                },{},{},{},{},
                                {
                                    colSpan: 6,
                                    rowSpan: 2,
                                    text: [
                                        {
                                            text: '\nCotação de preços',
                                            encoding: 'utf-8',
                                            style: {fontSize: 20}
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    alignment: 'center',
                                    style: {bold: true},
                                    border: [true, true, false, false]
                                },
                                {},{},{},{},{},
                                {
                                    text: [
                                        {
                                            text: `Nº\n `,
                                            encoding: 'utf-8',
                                            fontSize: 12, //16
                                            alignment: 'center'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: (modelRes['ENTNUM'] || ''),
                                            encoding: 'utf-8',
                                            alignment: 'center',
                                            style: {
                                                bold: true,
                                                fontSize: 12 //16
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: `\n\nEmissão: ${emiCotacao}`,
                                            encoding: 'utf-8',
                                            alignment: 'center',
                                            style: {
                                                bold: true,
                                                fontSize: 10
                                            }                                       
                                        }   
                                    ],
                                    colSpan: 2,
                                    rowSpan: 2,
                                    border: [true, true, true, false]
                                },{}
                            ],
                            
                        );          
                        //[... here I create the rows and columns]

                        pdfStream(docDefinition, resolve, reject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking that the font you have selected supports the accented character you are after.

Comment: Thanks for remembering, but yes, the font supports it, it's the same font I used in other applications to generate PDFs, and they support accents. Could it be something else? I'm using RedHat Linux

Comment: A quick search and I can see other user on Linux are facing issues like they can’t input accent characters at all, the one who could have special Portuguese keyboard. 
Don’t want to push you to buy one. However test accent characters locally on your machine if you can print them at all on terminal or text editor. 
This might give you clue as if it’s PDFMake issue!